# How to change the date format that primefaces give with this calendar?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

Hi I want to get this format date 2017/02/01 and we have got it just visual but when I insert this is the format that intruduce: Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2017. Im using that method to primefaces:

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarView.date1}" pattern="yyyy/dd/MM" binding="#{inputcalendar}"/>
```

[primefaces calendar code](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml)

Comment: p:caledar work like a input text or at least as shown, im so much lost with this component

Comment: oh ok, Im new on jsf, I'm using binding for get the value, how i could do it without binding?

Comment: Ok thanks you, I'll try it